# couldn't find file 'bootstrap' but it exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I cloned a Rails 4.1.7 project from git and now have an exception:

```
couldn't find file 'bootstrap'
  (in my_app/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css:13)
```

My appli-on.css:

```
 *= require bootstrap
 *= require font-awesome
 *= require s3_direct_upload_progress_bars
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
```

Gemfile:

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
```

Comment: is bootstrap file present in stylesheets directory under assets ?

Comment: @MuhammadYawarAli, no, but in Gemfile yes.

Comment: `bundle exec rails s`

Comment: I think you should go through this link : https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass for proper sass installation to work with `bootstrao-sass`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [README](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass)...

You need to ensure you have both `bootstrap-sass` and `sass-rails` gems installed and in your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 3.2'
```

You will also need to change your `application.css` to `application.scss`. It would look something like this:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";

//= require font-awesome
//= require s3_direct_upload_progress_bars
//= require_tree .
//= require_self
```

Comment: should I remove application.css?

Comment: Yes. The `application.scss` would take it's place.

Comment: I have shared the link : https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass above in comments read through it for solution it has all the needed commands.